# Two catches in one function

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I'm having some trouble getting two try-catches to work within one function, I'm quite new to JS and not exactly familiar with the functionality and limitations for try-catch. Currently working with a mongoDB database (Using mongoose). This is my code:

```
async function calcPoints() {
ClanMember.countDocuments({}, async function (err, count) {
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ClanMember.findOne({
            _id: i
        }, async (err, res) => {
            try {
                //removed most of the code as it's quite long and irrelevant to my issue, just collecting info here
                PointTrack.findOne({
                    membershipId: membershipId
                }, async (err, res) => {
                    try {
                        //removed the code, if the id was found it updates the document
                    }
                    catch(err) {
                        //removed the code, if the id was not found it creates a new document 
                        done(err, null);
                    }
                })
                
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log("Something went wrong");
                done(err, null);
            }
        })
    }
})
};
```

When i try to run the code i get this error code:

```
const { catch } = require("../database/database");
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

Comment: Uh, `const { catch } = require("../database/database");` is not part of the code you posted?

Comment: What is `done(…)`? You should not mix promises with callbacks. Similarly you should not pass an `async function` as callback.

Comment: ```const { catch } = require("../database/database");``` is one of the modules being imported, the module just connects to the database: ```const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 module.exports = mongoose.connect('link to connect to database', 
 { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:  true }); ```

As mentioned i am quite new to JS and although i very much appreciate your answer @Bergi it would be fantastic if you have a suggestion for how i can make this work, as im frankly not sure what to do here

Comment: `catch` is a keyword, you cannot use it as a variable name. Also you seem to export a promise, why would you want to access its `catch` method only? Just do `const db = require(…);`

Comment: It seems to work after changing { catch } to db and removed the done part, thank you